# SQL - Parse a field and SUM numbers at regular delimiter intervals

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, adobe-analytics

I request your help for an issue beyond my current skills...

I'm using Google Big Query to store analytics data about my website, and to calculate the revenue I have a quite difficult query to build.

We have the field %product% which is formatted as following :

```
;%productID%;%productQuantity%;%productRevenue%;;
```

If more than one product has been bought, the different products data will be delimited by ",", which can give this :

```
;12345678;1;49.99;;,;45678912;1;54.99;;
;45678912;2;59.98;;,;14521452;2;139.98;;,;12345678;2;19.98;;
;14521452;1;54.99;;
```

The only way to calculate the revenue is to sum all the different %productRevenue% from a line and store this into a column.

I have no idea how to do it just with a SQL query... Maybe with RegEx ? Any idea ?
I'd like to create a view with that info to easily pull the data into PowerBI then. But maybe I should process that with M directly in PBI ?

Thanks a lot,

Alex

Comment: I would ask if you have alternatives to this awful data format.  BigQuery supports arrays and records.  Even in a string-based format, you could have different delimiters for the different types of data.  Although what you want to do is possible, I strongly recommend a more reasonable data model.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Well, this is data we receive from raw datafeeds from Adobe Analytics and we have to adapt to it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  SPLIT(i, ';')[OFFSET(1)] productID,
  SUM(CAST(SPLIT(i, ';')[OFFSET(2)] AS INT64)) productQuantity,
  SUM(CAST(SPLIT(i, ';')[OFFSET(3)] AS FLOAT64)) productRevenue
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(product)) i
GROUP BY productID
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row productID   productQuantity productRevenue   
1   12345678    3               69.97    
2   45678912    3               114.97   
3   14521452    3               194.97
```

Comment: Awesome Mikhail, it works and it made me undestand the nested columns concept so I could adapt it to another use. Thanks a lot.